# I'm getting the CannotDetermineGraphQLTypeError and can't fix it

Tags: typescript, graphql, typeorm

My code:

```
@InputType()
export class RegisterUserInput implements Partial<User> {
  @Field()
  id!: number;

  @Field()
  userName!: string;

  @Field()
  firstName!: string;

  @Field()
  lastName!: string;

  @Field()
  password!: string;

  @Field()
  role!: string;

  @Field((type) => [Assignment])
  assignments!: Assignment[];
}
```

CannotDetermineGraphQLTypeError: Cannot determine GraphQL input type for 'assignments' of 'RegisterUserInput' class. Does the value used as its TS type or explicit type is decorated with a proper decorator or is it a proper input value?

Comment: not sure but this looks a bit funky: `@Field((type) => [Assignment])`

Comment: This is the syntax for having a field of a custom class

Comment: can you show me some docs where you found this syntax?

Comment: https://typegraphql.com/docs/types-and-fields.html

Comment: where is the definition of the Assignement class ? The error is saying that you haven't created an @InputType for the class Assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the user class has the @ObjectType() decorator.
else delete your build folder and rebuild again

Answer (score 0):

This is still a temporary work-around but it worked for me.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-type-json

```
  @Field((type) => [GraphQLJSONObject])
  assignments!: Assignment[];
```

Comment: Thank You! This work-around is useful, but I found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using InputType instead for Assignment

```
@InputType() // Define Assignments a separate InputType
class Assignment{
  @Field()
      name: string;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Thank you to who answered,
I found a solution by using 'simple-array' type.

Comment: Please elaborate on your solution